# How to reduce Zoom meeting data consumption on Windows 10 PC?

Tags: bandwidth, zoom-meeting

My internet bandwidth consumption is approaching the ISP cap. I checked bandwidth consumption and found that by far the heaviest user is a laptop (laptop A) used for ZOOM meeting (school), using 13GB of data in 3 hours. However, a different laptop (laptop B) does not use nearly as much data. Only 2GB or so in the same period. I suspect it has to do with video sharing done by others.

I checked the laptop A and make sure the "HD" under video camera is already unchecked. What else can I do to limit ZOOM data consumption?

Comment: See https://it.cornell.edu/zoom-zoomforcourses/reducing-zoom-data-and-bandwidth-use . Of course, turning off video or muting audio for the whole meeting only serves a purpose if you're strictly a *viewer*.

Comment: School requires students to keep video on. Audio is muted anyway in a class setting, audio doesn't use much bandwidth anyway. And as I mentioned above, HD is already unchecked.

Comment: Then all that's left is screen-sharing, which is probably done by the instructor, so should cost you nothing. Also, I imagine that video features, such as :makeup", mustache, and green-screen, *might* cost some throughput, if implemented at Zoom's end... or not.

Comment: I also found [this](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/160813-how-throttle-own-bandwidth-reduce-data-consumption-during-zoom.html) link.